# Get assembly version of another project (.exe)

Tags: c#, ipc, assemblyversions

I have source code of two C# projects. Project A starts project B (`process.Start();`). From project B I need to get assembly version of project A.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you looking out for something like

`AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("ProjectB.exe").Version`